# On organising methods within a class folder

Tags: matlab, class, methods

Let's say I have a couple of sets of methods that deal with: Disc I/O, Calculations, Testing etc. Is it possible to organise a class folder, so that the certain methods would be in their subfolders? Something like:

```
@MyClass/MyClass.m         % class definition
@MyClass/IO/ReadFile.m
@MyClass/IO/WriteFile.m
@MyClass/IO/EraseFile.m
@MyClass/Graphics/CreateWindow.m
@MyClass/Graphics/DeleteWindow.m
@MyClass/Tests/TestInputs.m
@MyClass/Tests/TestOutputs.m

% etc.
```

If I can have subfolders, how do I refer to methods?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't according to http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html. Class methods must be directly below the `@MyClass` path. Maybe you need more classes? Sounds like `MyClass` has a lot of responsibility.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually a good idea on separate class definitions. I did not realise my class would grow so much

Comment: So it sounds like you should create multiple class folders and function files within a [package namespace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html#brfynt_-2).  Using packages not only let's you encapsulate your functions and class names from the rest of the still relatively flat Matlab namespace, but they can also be nested, unlike class folders.

Comment: Why not just use `classdef` OOP syntax and have all class methods in a single file? The ability to create classes /methods in separate files / folders with `@` pre-dates the newer OOP syntax and, I believe, is only still there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Thanks for the clue.

Comment: @nirvana-msu Well, I'll stick to my way and have separate files for individual functions. It's easier to read and maintain the code